# Different ways to invoke contract method

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, truffle

I have one contract with method name as getValues().From Dapp I am invoking contract method as 'contractCAt.getValues.call(function(error,result){...})' this works fine and by using 'contractCAt.getValues(function(error,result){...})' this syntax also works fine.I didn't get any difference between those two ways to invoke contract method.So could anyone help me to give idea about those syntax.

Answer (score 1):

See the [web3j documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#contract-methods):

- `contractCAt.getValues.call()` is run locally and will not alter the state of your contract on the blockchain. Does not consume any ether.
- `contractCAt.getValues.sendTransaction()` does alter the state (assuming the transaction is successfully mined).
- `contractCAt.getValues()` automatically delegates to one of the two above based on the method definition. Constant and pure functions will use `call()` while the rest will use `sendTransaction()`.

Comment: If I close geth console once it has finished sync,if I reopen the geth console on same node will I get same account and wallet.